# displaying data from sql server in highchart time series line chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I am a first time user of high charts. I am trying to display table data (from sql server) in through highcharts using zoom-able time-series line chart. I want to plot a value-time line chart which can be zoomable based on the date. Can anyone help me

Table:

```
 tbl_values
```

columns:

```
   Time datetime,
    Value int

JSON data:
[{"Time":"2017-08-17 16:35:28.000","Value":"3.85"},
  {"Time":"2017-08-17 17:36:28.000","Value":"3.85"},
  {"Time":"2017-08-17 18:35:28.000","Value":"3.86"},
  {"Time":"2017-08-17 19:35:28.000","Value":"3.86"},
  {"Time":"2017-08-18 07:35:28.000","Value":"3.87"},
  {"Time":"2017-08-18 18:35:28.000","Value":"3.86"},
  {"Time":"2017-08-18 19:35:28.000","Value":"3.86"},
  {"Time":"2017-08-18 20:35:28.000","Value":"3.87"},
  {"Time":"2017-09-18 07:35:28.000","Value":"3.87"},
  {"Time":"2017-09-19 18:35:28.000","Value":"3.88"},
  {"Time":"2017-09-18 19:35:28.000","Value":"3.88"},
  {"Time":"2017-09-20 20:35:28.000","Value":"3.88"},
  {"Time":"2017-10-18 07:35:28.000","Value":"3.87"},
  {"Time":"2017-10-18 16:35:28.000","Value":"3.88"},
  {"Time":"2017-10-08 19:39:28.000","Value":"3.89"},
  {"Time":"2017-10-18 20:35:28.000","Value":"3.90"},
  {"Time":"2017-11-18 07:35:28.000","Value":"3.87"},
  {"Time":"2017-11-18 16:35:28.000","Value":"3.85"},
  {"Time":"2017-11-19 19:39:28.000","Value":"3.85"},
  {"Time":"2017-11-20 20:35:28.000","Value":"3.91"},
  {"Time":"2017-12-14 07:35:28.000","Value":"3.90"},
  {"Time":"2017-12-15 16:35:28.000","Value":"3.90"},
  {"Time":"2017-12-16 19:39:28.000","Value":"3.93"},
  {"Time":"2017-12-27 20:35:28.000","Value":"3.91"},
  {"Time":"2018-01-14 06:35:28.000","Value":"3.88"},
  {"Time":"2018-01-15 17:35:28.000","Value":"3.86"},
  {"Time":"2018-01-16 14:39:28.000","Value":"3.86"},
  {"Time":"2018-01-27 20:35:28.000","Value":"3.87"}
]
```

Comment: Provide us with a JSON containing your data.

Comment: adding following does the work tried at my end

chart: {
            zoomType: 'x'
        },

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-time-series/

Comment: @d_paul i have added the json data

Comment: I prepared a simplest example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/uaufnrn6/. Note that you will receive an error #15 (https://www.highcharts.com/errors/15) as your data is not sorted.

Comment: thanks. Is it possible to zoom in based on the date(month and time)